# How to use multi dimensional array in java instead of using array list?

Tags: java

I wan to use multi dimensional array in java. instead of using arrayList. I am trying to rework on my code. I automate my app to select a game, but need to store in every row of data in string array....so i can loop through each row by row to check the game date, hometeam name and away team name whether matching or not ?

```
WebElement listView = AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("ListView1");
List<WebElement> row = listView.findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'item')]"));
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outerList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        for (int a = 0; a < row.size(); a++) {
            ArrayList<String> innerList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<WebElement> column = row.get(a).findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'text')]"));
            if(!column.isEmpty()){
                for (int j = 0; j < column.size(); j++)
                {
                    innerList.add(column.get(j).getAttribute("Name"));
                }
                outerList.add(innerList);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(outerList);



for (int i = 0; i < outerList.size(); i++) {
        if ((outerList.get(i).contains(game_date)) && (outerList.get(i).contains(home_team_name)) && (outerList.get(i).contains(away_team_name))) {
            WebElement line_up1 = AppSession.findElementByName(game_date);
            line_up1.click();
        }
    }
```

this is how my gui app looks like for game selection...

> ```
>  Game date                   home team             away team
>     06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM     Ball Hogs Ball Hogs    Tri-State Tri-State
>     06/29/2018 08:00:00 PM     Power                  Ghost BALLERS
>     06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM     Killer 3's             3's Company
> ```

outer list  like this ::

```
[[06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM ,Ball Hogs Ball Hogs ,Tri-State Tri-State],[06/29/2018 08:00:00 PM, Power, Ghost BALLERS],[06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM, Killer 3's, 3's Company]]
```

How to use multi dimensinal array instead of using array list in java

```
                WebElement listView = AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("ListView1");        
                List<WebElement> row =listView.findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'item')]"));
                String[][] records = new String[row.size()][5];//11
                System.out.println(row.size());//11
                for(int a = 0; a < row.size(); a++)
                {
                    List<WebElement> column = row.get(a).findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'text')]"));              
                    if(!column.isEmpty()){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                        records[a][j] = column.get(j).getAttribute("Name");
                       System.out.println(records[a][j]);


                    }

                }
                }
```

System.out.println(records.length); //row count 10
        System.out.println(records[0].length); //column count 5

```
    for(int lineNum=5;lineNum<records.length;lineNum++) {

        for(int colNum=0;colNum<5;colNum++)
        {

         if ((records[lineNum][colNum].contains(game_date)) && (records[lineNum][colNum].contains(home_team_name)) && (records[lineNum][colNum].contains(away_team_name))) 
         {

             WebElement line_up1 = AppSession.findElementByName(game_date);
             line_up1.click();
             AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("btnDelete").click();
             AppSession.findElementByName("Yes").click();
             WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(AppSession, 5);
             wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("OK")));
             AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("2").click();
             line_up1.click();
             AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("btnOk").click(); 


         }
     }  
    }
```

output

```
06/22/2018 09:00:00 PM
Indiana Fever
Seattle Storm
WNBA
5
07/22/2018 02:00:00 PM
Seattle Storm
Atlanta Dream
WNBA
5
08/01/2018 09:00:00 PM
Phoenix Mercury
Las Vegas Aces
WNBA
5
```

it is click on eclipse top most left restore view.. it is not click on the respective game..why ?

this is the data i am getting,I have data from backend. like gamedate, hometeamname and awayteam name.. i am stored in 3 variables. but how to do check with gamedate, hometeam, awayteam. whether if it matches then i need to select ?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with a multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** you should clearly understand why you need multidimensional array here. There is a number of aspects that makes using arrays conceptually different from using lists.

Thus when you create an array **you have to know which size that array would have**. Unlike the lists which allow you to dynamically add new elements.

Multi-dimensional arrays are defined in the way:

```
String[][] records = new String[10][3];
```

which means you're creating **2-d array or in other word an array of arrays**. In above example you're creating an array of `10` items each of which contains an array of `3` items.

**Summary:**

1. You should evaluate how many entries are there on your UI (`numberOfRows`)
2. You cannot have variably number of columns so that you have to define the number of columns each line will contain (`numberOfCols`)
3. You then populate the array using the loop like described below:

-

```
String[][] records = new String[numberOfRows][numberOfCols];

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
    List<WebElement> column = row.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'text')]"));
    for(int j = 0; j < numberOfCols; j++){
        records[i][j] = column.get(j).getAttribute("Name");
    }
}
```

-

4. Then you just check your conditions using the access to the array elements like `records[lineNum][colNum]`

Comment: How do you think what could be the reason?

Comment: please let me know whether i correct for comparison?  or any  other approach like compare 2d array with single array....single array (db data)

Comment: I believe this is not connected with arrays approach. looks like it's something with how you locate elements.

Comment: @ Alexey R.   selecting the respective match is taking more time.. any other way like 2d array with 1d array comparison

Comment: What exactly does take slow? Performance of UI interaction does not depend on how you approach to store elements.

Comment: `records[lineNum][rowNum]`? I guess, you meant `records[lineNum][columnNum]`.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I just check to print hello inside if condition.. it is not printing and click on eclipse top on area..

Comment: @AlexeyR. it is click on top most left in the eclipse..why not selecting game ?

Comment: I cannot give you any advice because 1 - I do not have the app you test, 2 - I do not have your code, 3 - looks like this is completely different issue that was originally raised in the question.

Comment: @AlexeyR. it is working..i 'm just increment the column as +1

Answer (score 0):

As mostly number of columns will be constant, so why not use List of the String array.

Simple Usage Example:

```
 import java.util.*;
    //...

    List<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    rowList.add(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
    rowList.add(new String[] { "d", "e", "f" });
    rowList.add(new String[] { "g", "h" });

    for (String[] row : rowList) {
        System.out.println("Row = " + Arrays.toString(row));
    } // prints:
      // Row = [a, b, c]
      // Row = [d, e, f]
      // Row = [g ,h]

    System.out.println(rowList.get(1)[1]); // prints "e"
```

By using List, the number of rows can grow and shrink dynamically also.